# "Starts With" Predicate Only Works With Hard-coded Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I was wondering if anyone can answer this. I am searching in my database for objects that have the property name. I am looking for any objects that have a name starting with a particular letter.

If I use:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name LIKE \"a*\")", toFind];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

I can find the object that starts with an "a".

```
NSString *toFind = @"a";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name LIKE \"%@*\")", toFind];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

But with this "items" is empty.

If I use the following:

```
NSString *toFind = @"apple";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name = %@)", toFind];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

I get one object named "apple" in items.

Any ideas why this is...?

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constants require double quotes which you have in the first example.  If you are passing in a variable with wildcard then your complete expression needs to be passed in:

```
NSString *variableWildcard = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@*", toFind];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name LIKE %@)", variableWildcard]; // variable
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name LIKE \"a*\")", toFind];       // constant
```

Comment: With that I got:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "(name LIKE[cd] %@*)

Answer (score 0):

I went back and re-read the documentation. If I use the following it works:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name LIKE[cd] %@)", [toFind stringByAppendingString:@"*"]];
```